# Developer Mode in Frappe

Tags: python, frappe

When do we need to set frappe in developer mode?

To do this, do following bench folder:

bench set-config developer_mode 1
bench clear-cache
bench setup requirements --dev

I get warning (see last line):

Installing first_frappe_app

```
$ ./env/bin/python -m pip install -q -U -e ./apps/first_frappe_app
INFO: Installing python development dependencies for frappe
$ /home/sdc/frappe-bench/env/bin/python -m pip install -q -r
./apps/frappe/dev-requirements.txt
WARN: dev-requirements.txt not found in first_frappe_app
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are developing a new application and you want to change your doctype, report to affect in-app directory that time developer_mode need to enable.

But if you only want to customize the existing form that time is not required that.

About your error, I think your custom app was not installed properly. Try to reinstall

Answer (score 0):

In order to to use developer mode properly you've to set "developer_mode": 1 in site_config.json file.

Then execute a few commands in following sequence:
Go to frappe directory and execute source ./env/bin/activate
then execute bench --help command in order to make sure bench is installed in your local environment. If not then install it using bench install frappe-bench
Then execute:
bench migrate
bench setup requirements
bench build

NOTE:
Please stop supervisor  and nginx using sudo service supervisor command and sudo service nginx stop

Then execute bench start command in order to start the frappe in developer mode.

NOTE 2:
If bench migrate command fails then make sure that you've supervisorctl service or bench start mode is in running.

Answer (score 0):

You turn on developer mode when you want to version control your changes.

The most common use case for this is custom apps. With developer mode on, all of your changes are saved to file. If you create a Doctype then view the directory for your app, you will see a folder for the newly created Doctype along with the relevant files.

This is different from Customize Form where your changes are stored in the database.